# Unable to get a type from different package in Scala

Tags: scala, build, sbt, sbt-idea

I have a project that consists of several subprojects. Let's say, I have three of them:
service
core
common

In my build.scala, I have the following definition

```
lazy val root = Project ("root", file("."), settings = Info.settings) aggregate(common, core, service)

lazy val common = Project("common", file("common"), settings = Info.settings)

lazy val core = Project ("core", file("appcore"), settings = Info.settings ++ Seq(libraryDependencies ++= dependencies)) dependsOn common

lazy val security = Project ("Service", file("service"), settings = Info.gatewaySettings ++ Seq(resolvers := packageResolvers, libraryDependencies ++= gatewayDeps)) dependsOn(common, core)
```

I use idea for development and therefore sbt-idea 1.4.0 for the generation of idea specific files.

I have created a class in 'common': `User` in package `com.project.common.domain` and I would like to use it from my 'Service' module. I can't. It simply doesn't see it. I have checked the iml file, it contains dependencies.

Have anyone seen this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that all classes for some reasons were created in /test/scala instead of /main/scala